# Ionic web and mobile with same coebase?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to start developing hybrid aps.

Currently im using Angular for developing Web aps, so i picked Ionic as It can be used with ionic.

But I would like to ask if it is possible to develop web app, mobile app(android/ios) within one codebase, and if it is good practice..

Or should i just create two codebases for both web and mobile platforms?

Comment: U can achieve a full functioning app as functions from one code base, but in case u need different designs or structuring (which could be more than 30% changing to achieve web) then its better to do double projects....like linked in its made on one codebase (Web and mobile) but it's not developed by ionic but I gave this example since its mostly same designs and functions used on both devices, just some small changes to hide or show buttons for big and small screen...

Answer (score 0):

A single code base is the whole point to Ionic and others.... web and mobile from a single source.